# Display corruption using multimonitor mode starting in Ubuntu 17.10 Radeon X1600

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, radeon, amd-graphics

I have an old HP nw8440 laptop with a Radeon X1600 (FireGL) which has served me very well on Ubuntu up to 17.04. 17.10 does NOT like a "tall" monitor on the left.

Here's what's happening.

Internal  display: 1900x1200
External Display: 1600x1200 (or 1200x1600 in portait mode)

Problem 1: Changing the video results in corruption of the screen, requiring reboot. I can live with that, it's just irritating.

Problem 2 (the real problem) I cannot put the portrait mode on the left side. 
Problem 2a: The icons are limited to the height of the shortest monitor.
Problem 2b: The pointe will "shadow" on to the second screen as if the displays overlap.

Desired solution: Behaving system with the tall monitor on the left.

Screenshot explanations:

This arrangement works (tall monitor on right side)

[Right side tall monitor, works great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf47x.png)

When I move the monitor to the left side, the screen corrupts.

[Left side tall, corrupted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbW2l.jpg)

I can reboot to get rid of the corruption, but the icons are stuck at the wrong height.

[Left Side wrong icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eatd.png)

Also, I will get a "shadow" or "echo" of the pointer on the left side monitor when it is in certain regions of the main screen. The echo is not rotated to the orientation of the monitor, and is not captured in the screenshot (only the main pointer is captured in the screenshot, not the echo). his is probably a third problem.

The same thing happens on the Unity windows manager or Xorg manager.

So, how might I report or characterize this bug or set of bugs?

Comment: Up until now you've been running Xorg. Now, 17.10 defaults to Wayland. Try in a Xorg session as it should work as before. Your graphics card is legacy since a long time ago, there are no other drivers to try.

Comment: If this happens in both Wayland and Xorg, you probably should start by filing a bug against the `linux` package in Ubuntu, as it seems like it may be an issue in the kernel driver side.

Comment: @Phillip I've got exact the same issue! Are you having any success?

Comment: None. I can stably run in Xorg mode with both monitors in landscape, using a reboot after each config change. It's not pretty, and I can't get mixed portrait and landscape. One of the answers points to a bug report.

Comment: How would I identify the appropriate upstream component with the problem?

Comment: For starters, try installing one more DE, e.g. KDE, check if it has the problem. It'd allow to determine if the problem is likely with Unity, or somewhere between driver and XServer.

Comment: It fails under Unity and Xorg - does that count? If not, I'll try KDE.

Comment: @PhillipRemaker by "Xorg" do you mean you've tested it with `xinit` ? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by making a fresh installation, upgrading to 64-bit 18.04 "Bionic Beaver" which properly supports multi-orientation multi-monitor on the HP nw8440 x1600 "FireGL" video.

Also, for some reason, using photos as background for lock screen and main screen prevented display corruption. When using the "Bionic Beaver" logo for lock and desktop screens, power save and lock screen returned to highly corrupted screens. I have no idea the root cause there, but using a photo background is a simple workaround against display corruption.

There may be some series of patches to make 17.10 32-bit work, but the move to 18.04 completely fixed it. There is some display corruption on the default wallpaper, but moving to a different wallpaper fixed that.

On an unrelated note, I couldn't enable the Wi-Fi in 18.04 until I went into BIOS and disabled WLAN, rebooted, re-enabled WLAN, rebooted, and enabled simultaneous LAN/WLAN in BIOS. Not sure which step solved the problem, but for the iwl3945 or iwlegacy driver, hey look more carefully at BIOS setting. Symptom was that the `phy0` was "hard blocked" when looking at `rfkill list all`.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar experience. I played around with the display settings while doing a random number of reboots. Now I got it managed. One screen in landscape mode on the left hand side, the other one on the right hand side in portrait mode. I think I should never touch this setting again until there is a valid update.

Regarding the mis-behaviour on the screen placement I found a Bug ticket here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1240929

Maybe you should ask [there](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center) where to report the other bugs.

Comment: How would I identify the appropriate upstream component with the problem?

Comment: FYI: This looks fixed in 18.04. See my answer to this question.