# Is the NW8440 with Radeon "FireGL" Radeon X1600 supported in Ubuntu 17.10 and later?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, radeon

Since 17.10, I have multiple monitor problems with Ubuntu. Most of the answers are of the form, "dude, your machine is old."

At what point do I give up and decide that the machine is officially unsupported and and roll back to 17.04 forever?

I'm happy to report, but I don't know if the team maintaining the AMD drivers or GNOME system (who are they?) will even give me the time of day since my machine is ancient and they have bigger fish to fry.

So, does anyone declare officially support or obsolescence? Or do we just bumble along and hope?

Comment: It is supported. Can you please be more clear about your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My specific problem is https://askubuntu.com/questions/975773/display-corruption-using-multimonitor-mode-starting-in-ubuntu-17-10-radeon-x1600, but it's not clear which path I should take by bug.  Gnome? AMD Drivers? Somewhere else? I don't even know how to narrow down the problem to a component for a sensible report to an appropriate upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by upgrading to 64-bit 18.04 "Bionic Beaver" which properly supports multi-orientation multi-monitor on the nw8440 x1600 "FireGL" video.

There may be some series of patches to make 17.10 32-bit work, but the move to 18.04 completely fixed it. There is some display corruption on the default wallpaper, but moving to a different wallpaper fixed that.